# Check if all values in a row are NaN and replace them with 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am have a pandas data frame that has about 2000  rows and 8000 columns. I am trying to check if there are any rows with all values are NaN and if that is the case then replace NaN with 0.
I am aware that we can use the below code to check but I am not sure on how to further build it to replace the NaN (s).

Note - I do not want to replace NaN on a column level.

Could someone please help?

```
df_june.isna().all(axis=1)  # to check if all values of a row are NaN.
```

Comment: `df.loc[df.isna().all(axis=1)] = 0`

Comment: @NuriTaş Is there a way I can make it as a if condition, where it checks for rows with all null values and only if there are any, it replaces them to 0 ?

Comment: I couldn't get your question, you may update your question with the expected output.

Comment: Never mind. Your solution helped me solve the problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna

```
df_june.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. But this will replace all the NaN in the entire df. I do not want to do that. I only want to replace the NaN on rows where all the values are NaN.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [None, "12", None], "b": [None, None, "34"]})
df[df.apply(lambda row: [row[x] is None for x in df.columns].count(True)==len(df.columns), axis=1)] = 0
print(df)
```